# excel 2010 how to close password protected file with other files open?

Tags: excel

I've got a pw protected excel 2010 file. I can only close it when there are no other excel files open. Also in the sub window for the file, no "x" is present. Since I normally have 5 or more files open, closing it down does mean I close all the other files, close the pw file and open the others again. I'm sure there's a simpler way, but I just can not find it.

Stupid litte question, but when I try to google it all that turns up are a thousand ways to crack password protected files. Thats not what I need.

Any help is much appreciated,

Arnold

Comment: You can't use `File>>Close` ?

Comment: Yep, it was a stupid question. Thanks Tim for pointing it out. Arghhh. Sorry waisting your time. Arrgghh again.